# Why my custom list view extending ListFragment not showing CAB?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contextual-action-bar

This is my ListAdapter class where i am using a Checkbox to check custom listview items. I want to invoke CAB on checkbox selection like Gmail app. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListGettersSetters>
{
    ArrayList<ListGettersSetters> arrayListGettersSetters;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;
    int Resource, i = 0, j = 0, checkedItemsCount = 0;
    Animation animation1;
    Animation animation2;
    CheckBox flipCheckBox;
    viewHolder holder;

    static class viewHolder
    {
        public CheckBox imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewData;
        public TextView textViewDetails;
    }   

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ListGettersSetters> arrayListGettersSetters) 
    {
        super(context, resource, arrayListGettersSetters);
        this.arrayListGettersSetters = arrayListGettersSetters;
        Resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.to_middle);
        animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.from_middle);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return arrayListGettersSetters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListGettersSettersgetItem(int position) 
    {
        return arrayListGettersSetters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        holder = new viewHolder();
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.imageView = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_for_checkBox);
            holder.textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_for_name_textView);
            holder.textViewData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_for_data_textView);
            holder.textViewDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_for_details_textView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textViewName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.textViewData.setText(getItem(position).getData());
        holder.textViewDetails.setText(getItem(position).getDetails());
        holder.imageView.setTag(position);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            { 
                flipCheckBox = (CheckBox) view;
                flipCheckBox.clearAnimation();
                flipCheckBox.setAnimation(animation1);
                flipCheckBox.startAnimation(animation1);
                setAnimListners(arrayListGettersSetters.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())));
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setAnimListners(final ListGettersSetters listGettersSetters)
    {
        AnimationListener animationListener = new AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) 
            {
                if (animation == animation1) 
                {
                    flipCheckBox.clearAnimation();
                    flipCheckBox.setAnimation(animation2);
                    flipCheckBox.startAnimation(animation2);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    listGettersSetters.setIsChecked(!listGettersSetters.isChecked());
                    setCount();
                }
            }

            public void setCount() 
            {
                if (listGettersSetters.isChecked()) 
                {
                    checkedItemsCount++;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (checkedItemsCount != 0) 
                    {
                        checkedItemsCount--;
                    }
                }

                Log.v("Checked items count", checkedItemsCount + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
            }
        };
        animation1.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
        animation2.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity.java class extends a list fragment, it can be used as a fragment in another activity. In this activity i am calling MultiChoiceModeListener on my listview inside ListFragment. I want to invoke CAB without using ABS.

```
public class ActivityFragment extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.folders_fragment_listview, null, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        objectsList = new ArrayList<FoldersFragmentGettersSetters>();

        fragmentListView = getListView();
        fragmentListView .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long offset) 
            {
            }
        });

        fragmentListView .setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        fragmentListView .setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) 
            {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) 
            {
                MenuInflater menuInflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) 
            {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
                {
                    case R.id.menu_delete:
                        actionMode.finish(); 
                    return true;

                    default:
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int position, long id, boolean checked) 
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just track the checked items in an array. you have maintained cunt in setCount. also pass the position and add it in an Array

Answer (score 0):

Add the selected item in an Array

```
ArrayList<ListGettersSetters> selected_items = new  ArrayList<ListGettersSetters>();

public void setCount(position) 
{
     if (listGettersSetters.isChecked()) 
     {

           // add the selected item in array 
           selected_items.add(arrayListGettersSetters .get(position));
           checkedItemsCount++;

           Log.v("Checked items count", checkedItemsCount + "");
     } 
     else 
     {

           // Remove the item which is unselcted
           selected_items.remove(position);
           if (checkedItemsCount != 0) 
           {
                checkedItemsCount--;

                  Log.v("Checked items count", checkedItemsCount + "");
            }
     }
}
```

So you need to pass position in `setAnimListners` as well

```
setAnimListners(arrayListGettersSetters.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())), position );
```

## Edit :

Call method to update the UI from setCount only :

```
public void setCount(position) 
{
    // after if else
    // your all other code will go here
    // lastly call this method
    ((YourActivity)context).updateView(selected_items.size());
}
```

In Activity :

```
public void updateView(Integer length) {

    if (length > 0) {
        // show
    } else {
        // hide
    }

}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: How to access this selected_items arral list in my main activity to perform null check? I am doing this: (listAdapter.selected_items != null) & it gives me a null pointer exception.

Comment: What is NULL here ? better to use getter and setter of selected_items and access it in Activity

Comment: I want to set the visibility of a view in my main activity to visible if selected_items contains atleast one object else the view becomes gone.

Comment: Ya then check what is NULL, is adapter NULL ?

Comment: Can u post some code snippet to do so. I shall be thankfull to you.

Comment: This also does not changing the view visibility on item checking.

Comment: But where have you written this? put it in a method and call this method from `setCount()`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but now my application gets crashed specifying class cast exception.